# Replacing custom html tags in react

Tags: reactjs

Have the following code in public/index.html

```
<body>
    <some-tag><some-tag>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var obj1 = document.getElementsByTagName('some-tag')[0];;
        obj1.innerHTML = 'abc';
    </script>
</body>
```

This renders abc into some-tag successfully if i just run index.html alone

However if I use React, i.e.

public/index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var obj1 = document.getElementsByTagName('some-tag')[0];;
        obj1.innerHTML = 'abc';
    </script>
</body>
```

and React component

```
class Abc extends Component {
   render() {
       return (<some-tag />)
   }
}
```

and index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Abc />
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It fails to manipulate the tag and show 'abc'. What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you mutating the dom that way when u have React in place?

Comment: A component render method must use return to return jsx elements which is missing in your react component

Comment: sorry missed that ... have edited the question

Comment: @ArupRakshit suppose its a constraint that I have to work with and the script is something that I have no control over and it works by locating by html tag. How should I go about doing it

Comment: you don't have controls on the react or just the script?

Comment: just the script

Answer (score 2):

The problems are various.

First when

```js
  var obj1 = document.getElementsByTagName('some-tag')[0];;
```

is executed there is not guarantee both that DOM is actually loaded and then that React has actually rendered the html of the component.

Second issue is that modify the react generated html is possible but it is an anti-pattern.

If you want to modify the behaviour of your rendering you have to act on react's components, if the parameter comes from a server/backend what you are you looking for is Server Side Rendering (SSR).